# How to search as you type in the File Dialog window in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, dialog

I want to search as I type in the *Browse File Dialog* window opened when upload/save files with a *Web Browser*.

Is there a way to achieve this in Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be sure that the focus is set on the list with the files and 'the search as you type' procedure will work:

[image: browse file]